# Angular4 changing navbar value in a child component

Tags: angular, module, routes, components

Let's assume we have a navbar with a dropdown allowing to choose a city. When we choose a city we are redirected to `http://Domain/:city` and normally the navbar dropdown should show the name of selected city instead of "choose a city".
The app component contains the navbar and a router outlet which redirect to component showing the informations of the city. This component gets the name of the city from URL with ActivatedRoute.

```
-- app.component.ts --
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

-- navbar.html--
<ul class="nav pull-left">
        <li class="dropdown pull-right">
          <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <span *ngIf="!_selectedCity">Choose a city</span>
            <span *ngIf="_selectedCity">{{ _selectedCity.name }}</span>
            <b class="caret"></b>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngFor="let city of _cities"><a [routerLink]="['', city.name]" (click)="selectCity(city)">{{ city.name }}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

In order to change the navbar dropdown from "Choose a city" to the name of the selected city, I add the onClick event and it works perfect. But how can I set the navbar's dropdown value to the city name if the user gets access to the city informations by typing the URL instead of choosing the city from the dropdown ?

Thank you

Comment: could you either add a working demo for the problem or show more of your component's and template's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to router event and check the url param in OnInit of the component to set the dropdown value:

```
 import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
 ...
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
 ...
 ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        console.log(params['cityName']); //or whichever you use
      });
  }
```

Comment: I thought about this solution, but I think that it's not the right one. Angular should allow to transfer data between components.

Comment: Which components? Also if user enters the url from the address bar there is no transfer

Comment: I maybe found a solution using a service to transfer data from one component to an other. I will follow those steps and I think it will solve my problem.
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: If you are looking for component interaction, angular docs are great: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction